# React + Mobx: 'this' is null when trying to update store

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Just getting started with Mobx & React and having trouble getting the store to update. I get error when clicking the button, which should update the 'me' property:

```
Store.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'me' of null
```

My store:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';

class Store {

    @observable me;

    constructor() {
        this.me = 'test';
    }

    change_me(){
        this.me = 'test 1';
        console.log(this); // null???
    }

}

const store = new Store();

export default store;
```

The component:

```
import React from "react";
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

export default class Layout extends React.Component{

    render(){

        var store = this.props.store;

        return(
            <div>
              <button onClick={store.change_me}>{store.me}</button>
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

I've probably missed some fundamental part of how this works, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 9):

Yes react execute event callbacks with `this` being null. Since you only give the `onClick` callback the `change_me` method and not the `store` as context.

## Solutions

You have to set the `this` context yourself. you can do this in the following ways

### bad practices:

as @Eduard said you can warp it into an arrow function. the Arrow function makes sure the `this` context stays the same in the function body:

```
<button onClick={() =>store.change_me()}>{store.me}</button>
```

You can also use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
<button onClick={store.change_me.bind(store)}>{store.me}</button>
```

this does basically the same thing.

Why are they bad practises? on every `render()` call, these methods are re-created. and can result in extra unnecessary re-renders.

### Good practices

mobx provides a `action.bound` which wraps the function with the proper this context:

```
@mobx.action.bound
change_me(){
    this.me = 'test 1';
}
```

Alternatively es6 class definition allows you to define the this context properly yourself:

```
@mobx.action
change_me = () => {
    this.me = 'test 1';
}
```

See the arrow function. behind the scenes: instead of defining the function/method on the prototype of the `Store` class. the method is created in the `constructor` so that the `this` context variable always matches the instance of the class.

so that:

```
var a = new Store(); // a.me = 'test'
var b = new Store(); // b.me = 'test'
a.change_me = b.change_me; // change_me function contains its own this context.
a.change_me(); // a.me = 'test' b.me = 'test 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `mobx` but `onClick={store.change_me}` is a problem because you are using a method on a class as a function (without `this`). You will have to use use something like:

```
onClick={event => store.changeMe(event)}
```

otherwise the binding to `store` is lost.

Also possible but less readable:

```
onClick={store.changeMe.bind(store)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - I've fixed it my separating it into a function within the component. But now I have another issue - the component doesn't re-render once the store is updated. I've created another question here if you care to take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702409/react-mobx-component-not-updating-after-store-change. I feel like I'm going mad.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sulthan mentioned, you need to have the method wrapped by another function `onClick={()=>store.changeMe()}`.
Second issue is you are missing `action` decorator for the method which updating the value. Mobx works in a way where every method which will update properties, it need to be decorated by `@action`. So following will fix the issue `import {action} from 'mobx`,

```
@action change_me(){
    this.me = 'test 1';
}
```